# Passing string as an argument inside a function in objective c

Tags: ios, function, arguments

I would like to pass NSStrring as argument while calling a function.

I am very much new to objective c. My function looks something like:

```
-(void) light_uri(NSString *)uri_temp
{
    NSString *base_uri = @"http://localhost:3000/";
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSString *uri_light = [base_uri stringByAppendingString: uri_temp];
    NSURL *url_light =[NSURL URLWithString: uri_light ];
    NSData* data_light = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url_light];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data_light waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

But I get an error `expected method body` and `undeclared identifier uri_temp`

Is it a right way to pass an string as argument or do i have to change something'?

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a syntax error in your method name, use:

```
-(void) light_uri:(NSString *)uri_temp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I almost forgot that.